# List of weakly NP-HARD problems

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, knapsack-problems, partitions, subset-sum

I need a list of at least 10 weakly NP-HARD problems. I already know the Knapsack problem, partition problem and subset sum problem. Please introduce other weakly NP-hard problems to me.

Comment: There are countably many weakly NP-Hard problems... it'll be hard to make a semi-complete list :)

Comment: Ok. I edit my question to know at least 10 weakly NP-HARD problems.